# basic jquery onload animation in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am completely new to this coffeescript thing but Rails seems to want me to use it, so I am giving it a try.

I sort of understand the basic examples on the coffeescript page but I'm not sure how to translate this jquery function into coffeescript

```
$(function() {
   $('#alert').delay(100).show("drop", { direction:"up" }, 900);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[InPursuit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631017/inpursuit) is correct but I believe `$ ->` is more of a coffee idiom.

```
$ ->
  $('#alert').delay(100).show 'drop', direction: "up", 900
```

... compiles to:

```
$(function() {
  return $('#alert').delay(100).show('drop', {
    direction: "up"
  }, 900);
});
```

Check out [this link](http://coffeescript.org/#try:$%20-%3E%0A%20%20$%28%27#alert%27%29.delay%28100%29.show%20%27drop%27,%20direction:%20%22up%22,%20900) to see it in action and also play with a coffee repl.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$(() ->
  $('#alert').delay(100).show('drop', {direction:"up"}, 900))
```